# Encerrar el valor de una variable entre comillas simples en BASH

Tags: bash

Estoy intentando adaptar unos scripts de `Perl` a `Bash` para correrlos en `Nagios XI`.

El problema está en que Nagios espera que los valores de las variables lleguen entre comillas simples, pero no consigo escapar las variables correctamente.

Por ejemplo, en la zona superior donde declaro variables y/o constantes, tengo esto:

```sh
status='OK'
```

Y cuando lo sustituyo en el valor a devolver a Nagios, lo pongo así y funciona correcto:

```sh
output="[$status]"
output_msg="Voting disks status check succeeded"
```

Lo cual al imprimirlo, devuelve ese `[OK] Voting disks status check succeeded`.

Sin embargo, tengo otras variables que construyo a partir de comandos ejecutados, tal que así:

```sh
comando=`/oracle/app/grid/19300/bin/crsctl query css votedisk | grep asm`
salida1=`echo $comando | cut -d " " -f4`
salida2=`echo $comando | cut -d " " -f5`
```

Si ejecuto este script en local, el resultado es el esperado:

```sh
[OK] Voting disks status check succeeded - (/dev/mapper/asm_ocr1) [OCR]
```

Pero al lanzarlo desde el servidor Nagios, las variables `$salida1` y `$salida2` siempre llegan vacías:

```sh
[OK] Voting disks status check succeeded -
```

Sé que es por las comillas simples porque probando a declarar una tercera variable con un texto literal, si que sale correctamente:

```sh
salida3='Prueba'
output="[$status] $output_msg - $salida3
```

Esto pinta en el servidor Nagios:

```sh
[OK] Voting disks status check succeeded - Prueba
```

¿Alguna idea de como meter el texto que contienen `$salida1` y `$salida2` entre comillas simples para que Nagios lo interprete?

**EDIT**

Para corroborar que el contenido de la variable debe estar entre comillas simples, he hecho la siguiente prueba:

```sh
#Añado la ruta que debe devolver $salida1
prueba='/dev/mapper/asm_ocr1'
#Pinto en el output la variable $prueba
output="[$status] $output_msg - $prueba $salida1 $salida2"

########

#En el servidor de Nagios, la variable $prueba viaja correctamente:
[OK] Voting disks status check succeeded - /dev/mapper/asm_ocr1 ''
```

**EDIT2**
He descubierto que el error no viene de las comillas, sino de la comunicación de Nagios con el nodo donde se ejecuta la BD.

El script completo, hasta ahora, es este:

```sh
. /home/oracle/.profile_RAC
ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/app/grid/19300
ORACLE_BASE=/oracle/app/base
nagios_exit_codes=('UNKNOWN', 3, 'OK', 0, 'WARNING', 1, 'CRITICAL', 2)
status='OK'
ok=1
action=$1

case $action in
        "votedisk")
                #command=`/oracle/app/grid/19300/bin/crsctl query css votedisk | grep asm`
                #command=$(/oracle/app/grid/19300/bin/crsctl query css votedisk)
                command=`/oracle/app/grid/19300/bin/crsctl query css votedisk`

                case $comando in
                        *"failed"*|*"OFFLINE"*|*"PROC"*)
                                status='CRITICAL'
                                output_msg="Voting disk status check failed!"
                        ;;

                        * )
                                output_msg="Voting disks status check succeeded"
                        ;;
                esac

                output="[$status] $output_msg - $command"

        ;;

        "clusterstatus")
                comando=`/oracle/app/grid/19300/bin/crsctl query crs releaseversion`
                output_msg="All clusterware services are up (clusterware version: $comando)"
                output="$output_msg"

        ;;
esac


echo -e $output
exit 0
```

Al ejecutar este script localmente, el resultado es el siguiente:

```sh
[root@bbddmachine plugins]# sh ./script_prueba.sh votedisk
[OK] Voting disks status check succeeded - ## STATE File Universal Id File Name Disk group -- ----- ----------------- --------- --------- 1. ONLINE 8dfc2a9528244f95bf87bb394e793995 (/dev/mapper/asm_ocr1) [OCR] Located 1 voting disk(s).
```

Pero en la máquina de Nagios, el resultado es erróneo:

```sh
[nagios@ng1esp libexec]$ ./check_nrpe -2 -H 172.47.62.12 -t 60 -c check_crs_votedisk
[OK] Voting disks status check succeeded - Unable to communicate with the Cluster Synchronization Services daemon.
```

Sin embargo, si lanzo la otra opción del script llamada `clusterstatus` todo funciona bien:

```sh
[nagios@ng1esp libexec]$ ./check_nrpe -2 -H 172.47.62.12 -t 60 -c check_crs_clusterstatus
All clusterware services are up (clusterware version: Oracle High Availability Services release version on the local node is [19.0.0.0.0])
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con `var=$(comando)`?

Comment: @fedorqui Si, pero a la hora de ejecutarlo en Nagios hace lo mismo, el valor de la variable no "viaja".

Comment: ¿Y si es el comando crsctl que no puede ejecutarse? Prueba con algo así como `var=$(echo "hola")` y luego usa `$var` para ver si esto sí funciona o no.

Comment: @fedorqui He añadido información en el EDIT2.

Comment: vale, tiene lógica. Entonces la gestión de la variable es correcta, lo que hay que corregir es el tema del comando

Comment: @fedorqui Lo que no tiene sentido es que uno si funcione y el otro no. Me trae por la calle de la amargura.

Comment: Ya entiendo :( parece un tema más de [dba.se]